# sidekiq worker is not getting triggered when rediscloud url is used in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I am new to Ruby on Rails, I am facing an issue where sidekiq with redis (redis://localhost:6379) on local is working fine(getting triggered) but is not working with rediscloud in heroku. What can be the issue?

My procfile contains:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q critical -q applications -q default
```

Comment: silly question, but how do you know it isn't getting triggered? What logfiles are you looking at? And do you know the port numbers in question?

Answer (score 0):

The wiki notes how to set up your Redis provider on Heroku:

```
heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISCLOUD_URL
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#using-an-env-variable

Comment: This is not working for me. I am getting `:exception_object=>#<SocketError: getaddrin
fo: Name or service not known>, :status=>500, :status_message=>"Internal Server Error"` and I have followed the instructions.